# How can I get these links and images to appear inline

Tags: html, css

This seems so simple but I seem to be failing at it for some reason. So I have 3 images and each image has a link above it. I want them to appear inline  and I can't use a table so I tried divs but they appear one after the other instead of inline. note: my page width is 1000px

```
   <!-- First Div with link and image-->
    <div style="float:left;width:33%">
       <a href="/bartop">BarTop Epoxy</a>
       <img style="margin: 15px;"src="image1" width="300" height="315">
    </div>
    <!-- Second Div with link and image--> 
   <div style="float:left;width:33%">
       <a href="/counter top"> Countertop</a>
       <img style="margin: 15px;" src="image2" width="300" height="315">
    </div>
     <!--third Div with link and image-->
    <div style="float:left;width:33%">
       <a href="/flooring">Flooring</a>
       <img style="margin: 15px;" src="image3" width="300" height="315">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please specify which browser you are using, the code above should work. Or add the container div and the related css

Comment: @Phlume last item don't need it

Comment: I was using chrome but clear none works  that or I was not taking into account the 15px on each side of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to check:

1. That the DIVs are not clearing--they should have `clear:none` declared or inherited.
2. That there is enough space in your container for all of these items. Your floats contain elements 300 pixels wide with an extra 30 pixels of margin. Is your container 990px wide? Or even 660px wide? Floats will bump down to underneath the previous float if there is not enough room for them.

Comment: That wasn't the problem but it was a good point that I need to account for the extra 30px

Comment: Actually, with the percentage declared, that won't happen in most browsers anyway. I would check inheritance (make sure there's not another rule overriding the `float` or clearing it).

Answer (score 0):

By default `divs` have a `display: block;` property, which means they will not appear on the same line.

You can fix this by making the display `float`, like you've done, but you should also add the styling `clear: none;` to be sure the floated elements are allowed to be side by side.

Alternatively, you could use `display: inline-block;`, which may work better for what you are trying to do, and [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utXfF/) with this option.

Comment: "By default divs have a display: block; property, which means they will appear side by side." Don't you mean one after another?

Comment: Yes, I misspoke. Edited.

Comment: also as far as I know, you don't need clear none to get 2 floating elements side by side as long as their total width does not exceed the container width (http://jsfiddle.net/WGyzw/)

Comment: It's not a bad idea for the user to add it in, since it sounds like they are still experimenting with their format and their ultimate goal is to make sure they can put divs side by side.

Comment: if clear none solves the issue then the cause is not in the code given